# Loading a website into String using a program language like Java

Tags: java

I want to be able to make a connection to a website but i don't want the website counter to track me and getting info about me.

So i want to ask if i use for example this Java code:

```
public class ConvertUrlToString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String webPage = "http://www.google.com";
            URL url = new URL(webPage);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

            int numCharsRead;
            char[] charArray = new char[1024];
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
                sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
            }
            String result = sb.toString();

            System.out.println("*** BEGIN ***");
            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.println("*** END ***");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

...will the website analytic engine(for example google) be able to track me and get information about me?

Comment: Yes. This is essentially no different than visiting the website with the browser. IIRC, the User-Agent when using URLConnection is automatically set to the version of java you are using, so the server you are contacting would be able to tell that you are accessing it programmatically, and not with a browser.

Comment: And what about javascript code that collects information for google analytics?